# save the output of a bash file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i have some files in a folder, and i need the first line of each folder

```
transaction1.csv
transaction2.csv
transaction3.csv
transaction4.csv
```

and i have the next code

```
#All folders that begin with the word transaction

folder='"transaction*"'

ls `echo $folder |sed s/"\""/\/g` >testFiles

# The number of lines of testFiles that is the number of transaction files

num=`cat testFiles | wc -l`

for i in `seq 1 $num`
do
    #The first transaction file
    b=`cat testFiles | head -1`

    #The first line of the first transaction file
    cat `echo $b` | sed -n 1p 

    #remove the first line of the testFiles
    sed -i '1d' testFiles 
done
```

This code works, the problem is that i need save the first line of each file in a file

and if i change the line:

```
cat `echo $b` | sed -n 1p > salida
```

it not works =(

Comment: Just put `exec >salida` at the very top of the script.

Answer (score 3):

In bash:

```
for file in *.csv; do head -1 "$file" >> salida; done
```

As Adam mentioned in the comment this has an overhead of opening the file each time through the loop. If you need better performance and reliability use the following:

```
for file in *.csv; do head -1 "$file" ; done > salida
```

Comment: Or, instead of `>> salida; done`, you could use `; done > salida`.  That way, you aren't reopening the file each time through the loop, and you will replace the file (if, for example, it was dirty from an earlier attempt) instead of appending to it.

Comment: On a side note: `head -1` is deprecated, use `head -n 1`.

Answer (score 2):

```
head -qn1 *.csv
```

`head -n1` will print the first line of each file, and `-q` will suppress the header when more than one file is given on the command-line.

**=== Edit ===**

If the files are not raw text (for example, if they're compressed with "bzip2" as mentinoned in your comment) and you need to do some nontrivial preprocessing on each file, you're probably best off going with a `for` loop.  For example:

```
for f in *.csv.bz2 ; do
    bzcat "$f" | head -n1
done > salida
```

(Another option would be to `bunzip2` the files and then `head` them in two steps, such as `bunzip2 *.csv.bz2 && head -qn1 *.csv > salida`; however, this will of course change the files in place by decompressing them, which is probably undesirable.)

Comment: and if i have compress all files with bzip2, the format of all files is .csv.bz2, and if i do a head with a bz2 it not works.

Answer (score 1):

this awk one-liner should do what you want:

```
awk 'FNR==1{print > "output"}' *.csv
```

the first line of each `csv` will be saved into file: `output`

Comment: and if i have compress all files with bzip2, the format of all files is .csv.bz2, and if i do the awk it not works, because the command can not print the files

Comment: ok, you never mentioned the bz2 part. who knows you have that requirement? if your file is gpg encrypted, no answer here works either. so, extract the package, then try the answers here.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
for f in *.csv; do sed -n "1p" "$f"; done >salida
```